# LINQ to SQL mapping without using attributes or external XML configuration

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to set up LINQ to SQL over an existing domain object, so I can simplify caller access to my repositories. I don't want to add attributes all over my domain object's class, and I don't want to have to maintain an external XML mapping file (even with tools like SQLMetal). I would prefer to define the mapping in code, similar to how Fluent NHibernate works. Is this possible, and how can it be achieved?

Comment: You're not addressing why Fluent NH is not working out for ya ...

Comment: I haven't tried FNH for this so far. It may be a better solution and I'm looking into it as well, I just couldn't figure out how to do the mapping in LINQ to SQL in the same way.

Comment: I havent tried EF4 yet, so I am not equipped for EF4 vs. FNH comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with LINQ to SQL. It *is* possible in the Entity Framework.

Comment: Is it possible in EF 3.5? I can only find reference to code mapping in EF4, and unfortunately I'm limited to 3.5.

Comment: No, EF 3.5 still needs an EDMX file.